# Можно мокать тестируемый обьект?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit, любой-язык

## Есть:

- Класс который нужно протестировать

  ```
    class Message extends Data
    {
       protected $text = '';

       public function check()
       {
          return empty($this->text);
       }

       public function setText($text)
       {
          if ($this->check() === true) {
             $this->text = $text;
          } else {
             $this->text .= $text;
          }
       }
    }
  ```
- Разработчики **Вася** и **Петя**, которые спорят как правильно написать
  тест для `setText`, нужно мокать метод `check` или нет?

### Вася: за mock `check`

При юнит тестировании нужно мокать все что возможно кроме спрятанных данных (`private, protected`), что бы протестировать все сценарии которые не зависят друг от друга. Итого будет 3 сценария, где мок `check` вернет либо `true`, `false` или иное, для метода `setText`. И отдельно протестировать метод `check`. Также незабыть компонентный тест, который протестирует обьект (`Message`) в общем, то есть интерфейс этого объекта, не мокая ничего что касаеться `Message` и `Data`.

### Петя: против mock `check`

Нельзя мокать методы тестируемого класса (`Message`) и его родителей (`Data`), можно только внешние классы. При изменении метода `check` реально сломается `setText` но юнит об этом не сообщит. Сами юниты будут показывать как работает класс, ненужно делать компонентные тесты только на один объект, но сами тесты будут дублировать в себе проверку одних и тех же внутренних зависимостей (метод `check`, будет 2 раза протестирован)

### Вопрос:

Кто из них прав, или как правильно тестировать?

### Примеченные:

Как обычно в моих вопросах, этот обучающий вопрос. Проблемы с конкретным кодом нету, это просто пример (на примерах лучше понять)

Comment: А вместо "мокать" что-то более понятное по русски написать можно?

Comment: по русски нету подходящего слова, "подменить" звучит отдаленно от тестирования

Comment: [Печально](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267). Но если взять за основу [перевод](https://translate.google.ru/#en/ru/mock) -- **макет**, то по смыслу надо говорить о *макетировнии* (а лучше, наверное, *моделировании* (обратите внимание на simulated в списке синонимов определения слова mock)) объекта. А в контексте функций imho на русском использовали термин *заглушка* (dummy).

Comment: Тогда вопрос будет звучать так, "Можно заглушить тестируемый обьект?" Кстате я не против если вы подберете удачный перевод и подправите мой вопрос

Comment: Сами подправьте (ну, не спец я по формулировкам). Я бы написал, *можно ли при таком тестировании заменять метод класса заглушкой?* (или *можно ли в такой ситуации использовать заглушку*) Вы же именно об этом?

Comment: @avp, заглушка это stub а не mock. Нельзя переводить эти термины в отрыве друг от друга!

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну так предложите свой вариант для mock (все же "мокать" это уже ни в какие ворота не лезет (хуже чем директория))

Comment: имитировать, сымитировать

Comment: @avp Не видел программистов, которые бы не называли моки моками. Скажите спасибо, что "мокать", а не "мочить" или "макать".

Comment: @Discord, все когда-нибудь случается в первый раз.

Comment: Например, «имитация» — вполне хорошее слово в этом контексте. «Подменить объект на имитацию» звучит намного понятнее, в отличие от очень уж корявого «мокнуть объект».

Answer (score 4):

За идею мокать тестируемый класс я бы сразу расстреливал. Тестируемый класс — это единое целое, и должно тестироваться как единое целое. Пролезая своими грязными ручками в метод `check`, вы предполагете конкретную реализацию метода `setText`. Это не юнит-тест, это профанация: вы тестируете не внешний интерфейс класса, а проверяете, что операции в нём написаны точно так же, как в тесте.

Где в интерфейсе класса говорится, что `setText` должен вызывать `check`, а не кэшировать состояние к какой-то переменной? Теперь вы не можете изменить реализацию при сохранении интерфейса и поведения, не сломав юнит-тесты. Так зачем же юнит-тесты, которые ломаются от изменения внутренней реализации? Они только раздражать будут.

Вот если какие-то методы тестируемого класса будет сложно тестировать (они будут лезть на внешние ресурсы, например), то тогда уже можно подумать о моках. Но в этом случае, скорее всего, логику залезания на внешние ресурсы надо выделить в отдельный класс и мокать уже его.

---

Я вообще сторонник идей Мартина Фаулера: мокать нужно только то, что слишком сложно не мокать: базы данных, рассылку почты и т. п. Это позицию он называет "[классическим TDD](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#ClassicalAndMockistTesting)".

Каждый раз, когда вы втыкаете мок в тестируемый код, вы подменяете реальное поведение, вы предполагете реализацию, вы имитируете поведение и делаете ошибки. Ваш код тестирует не реальную систему, а имитацию.

Да, тесты с минимумом моков чаще ломаются охапкой, а не поодиночке. Но зато они ломаются! И если они ломаются, то сразу видно, что где-то есть реальная ошибка. Если же тесты тестируют реализацию, то они ломаются поодиночке, но общие для нескольких классов ошибки не ловятся, а проваленные тесты часто просто указывают на изменение реализации.

"Мокеры" любят плодить миниатюрные юнит-тесты на каждый геттер и сеттер, но забывают, что классы существуют не в безвоздушном пространстве, а взаимодействуют. В результате у каждого класса покрытие 99%, а вместе почему-то всё ломается. Нельзя забывать про интеграционные тесты. И юнит-тесты, которые "слегка интеграционные" — это отличный путь.

Не бойтесь вызвать метод из десятка разных мест: чем больше реальных вызовов, тем больше уверенности в надежности системы.

---

Что касается конкретно вашего кода, то у вас метод выглядит как сеттер, но по сути им не является. Это провал теста до написания каких-либо тестов.

Comment: мир станет проще, если отказаться от классических юнит-тестов, а использовать только юнит-тесты, которые "слегка интеграционные"?

Comment: @duhon Мир станет лучше, если не увлекаться любой идеей до одури, в данном случае не доводить изоляцию тестов с помощью моков до абсурда, когда от тестируемого класса остаётся пол-метода, и эти пол-метода тестируются на реализацию. Ну а откуда вы взяли, что "классические юнит-тесты" — это непременно с моками, я не знаю. См. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TenYearsOfTestDrivenDevelopment

Comment: сори я не просто так на русской версии этого сайта :(

Comment: @duhon Не понял, к чему вы это.

Comment: Неважно. Согласны ли вы что юнит-тесты которые мокают все не проверяют логику приложения? А компонентный тест может проверить интерфейс работы класса?

Comment: @duhon Юнит-тесты, которые мокают всё, часто проверяют слишком мало и слишком оторванно от реального кода (читать: они полезны, но не слишком эффективны), а моки часто приводят к тестам реализации (читать: с моками легко свалиться к хрупким тестам). / Второй вопрос не понял. Вы под "компонентным" подразумеваете юнит/модульное, интеграционное или какое-то другое? И даже с этим уточнением вопрос не понял.

Answer (score 2):

В данном конкретном случае я бы изменил интерфейс. Метод `setText` выглядит как обычный сеттер, но в действительности сеттером не является.

Очень похоже, что его стоит разбить на методы `clearText` и `appendText`, и вынести логику, спрятанную за `check`, выше.

Спор Васи с Петей косвенно свидетельствует о проблемах в проекте.
Позиция Пети сильнее (нельзя мокать методы тестируемого класса), поскольку она соответствует правилам декомпозиции, описанным у книге дядюшки Боба Мартина «Чистый код».

Если кратко: на одном слое декомпозиции должны находиться методы одного логического уровня, такой код гораздо проще читать. В Вашем примере всё выглядит так, что `check` должен находиться где-то выше, где его и надо тестировать. И вот там можно мокать класс `Message`, который находится на уровень ниже.

И здесь, на уровне `Message`, мы можем протестировать методы `clearText` и `appendText`, возможно, мокая какие-то классы ниже.

P.S. Замечу, что в реальных проектах не всегда возможно правильно позиционировать сущности по уровням, так что Вася с Петей рискуют до хрипоты обсуждать и этот вопрос.

P.P.S. Заметил, что речь идёт о моках. Я по возможности следую такому правилу: сначала протестируй непосредственно, если не выходит, и нельзя перепроектировать, задействуй стаб, если и так не выходит, задействуй мок. Таким образом простые валидирующие или трансформирующие методы, которые работают с объектами стандартной библиотеки (строки, даты, регулярные выражения) перетекают в классы-утилиты, где и тестируются.

Comment: Тоесть ваш ответ за Петю, но с оговоркой что при правильной архитектуре такого бы вопроса не возникло

Comment: Да, за Петю. Вася немного максималистично подходит к вопросу. У меня в одном проекте объём тестов в полтора раза превышает тестируемый код. После такого опыта я лично сомневаюсь, что «надо мокать всё, что возможно».

Comment: просто я сейчас на проекте где много юнитов, один баг подправил за день, и уже два дня правлю юнити которые очень косвенно связаны с изменениями. А было бы замокано, то правил бы точечно в нужных сценариях, и одно-двух интеграционных и функциональных тестов. А сейчас я вижу что тесты сломались а функционал нет.

Comment: К сожалению, очень трудно давать универсальные советы в данной области, не видя кода.

Comment: @duhon, если вы уже решили для себя, что лучше мокать, то зачем тогда вопросы задавать? Или вы просто ищите одобрения вашего подхода со стороны коллег?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Я решил это 4 года назад. До разделения уровней тестирования, были написаны тесты, которые мешали коду развиваться ("этот код менять нельзя, там сломается десятки тестов"). Но что бы сломать стереотип я обратился к обществу программистов, что бы услышать как вы решили эту проблему. Пока что я услышал что архитектура плохая, и что менять кучи тестов правильно, ведь архитектура плохая, или что юнитами называют почти все тесты которые пишут на phpunit

Comment: @duhon Смысл тестов в том, чтобы тестировать. Если при изменении реализации ломается множество несвязанных тестов в разных местах, то это признак, что с тестами что-то не так. Например, в тесты понатыканы избыточные проверки, которые не связаны с тестируемой логикой. Или внешнее поведение тестируемых классов в третьем колене слишком зависит от реализации какого-то класса. Причин много. В общем случае дать совет сложно.

Comment: @duhon Что касается использования phpunit для любых тестов, то слово "unit" в названии — это условность, просто так исторически сложилось. Функционала *Unit фреймворков на любых языках хватает для тестов многих типов. / Кстати, если с моками перемудрить, то тесты тоже могут охапками падать. Суёшь в базовый класс запрос чего-нибудь — и всё полетело с исключениями "не замокано".

Answer (score 1):

У вашего класса не полный API. Добавьте метод `getText` и тестируйте поведение *комплексно*.

Как вариант можно использовать следующие тесты:

1. На чистом объекте, убедиться, что `check` возвращает `false`.
2. На чистом объекте, убедиться, что `getText` возвращает `''`.
3. После `setText` метод `check` возвращает `true`.
4. После `setText` метод `getText` возвращает правильную строку.
5. После повторного `setText` метод `getText` возвращает правильную строку.

---

**Небольшое отступление:**

Некоторые методы очень трудно тестировать в изоляции друг от друга и это нормально. Типичный пример -- контейнер:

```
class Container {
    private $data;

    public function get(key) {/* ... */}

    public function set(key, value) {/* ... */}
}
```

Методы `get` и `set` просто нельзя протестировать отдельно друг от друга. В таких случаях имеет смысл тестировать *поведение* объекта (либо группы методов).

Кроме того, правильнее подходить к методам как к маленьким "черным ящикам". Тесты ни в коем случае не должны зависеть от реализации метода. В вашем примере, стоит вам заменить вызов `check` на что-то еще и ваши тесты сломаются, хотя *поведение* метода `setText` останется прежним.

Тестирование не должно быть самоцелью. Поэтому, использовать какие-то хитрые приемы (моки тестируемого объекта, наследование, с целью раскрытия структуры и прочее) в большинстве случаев неправильно. Тесты -- это всего лишь инструмент, позволяющий гарантировать, что код работает.

Comment: я так понял вы за утверждение Пети? :)

Comment: я просто за Васю болею. 
Если трудно протестировать метод в изоляции, значит метод пахнит сильной связаностью. Также я считаю что юнит тесты не проверяют  логику приложения, а нужны только для определения проблем и только в момент напания кода (например tdd). А реальную ценость в тестировании приносят компонентные (показывают как работает компонент), интеграционные (показывают как работает в связке), функциональные (проверяют логику приложения)

Comment: В целом да, но по другим причинам. Обновил ответ

Comment: @duhon, "_Если трудно протестировать метод в изоляции, значит метод пахнит сильной связаностью._" вы не правы. В ответе я привел типовой пример нетестируемых методов. Вообще, тесты не должны знать о том, как реализованы методы. Это как инкапсуляция в классах, только на более мелком уровне

Comment: @duhon, ну и модульные тесты это не панацея и уж точно не должно быть вашей самоцелью. Даже если вы используете TDD это не должно превращаться в культ карго

Comment: вы описали класс который можно протестировать не ниже интеграционного теста. Некоторые программисты всё называют тестами, не видя разницы между уровнями, из за этого иногда пишут юниты на такие классы, и наоборот на сложные классы пишут функциональные, а потом не могут понять почему потратили время, а приложение работает нестабильно, а потом еще такие тесты начинают тянуть код в безну (выражение: блин тут править нельзя иначе тесты придется переписывать). Я считаю что нужен определенный тип ножа для конкретного продукта.

Comment: @duhon, Ну тогда не используйте модульные тесты для таких случаев. Вообще.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31860/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-duhon).